# Opening documents inside Dropbox iOS app

Tags: dropbox, ios

I have installed drop box iOS app. It syncs with the documents that I have on the pc. Is there any way I can open a word/excel file inside the drop box app with a document editing app like Documents, iSpreadsheet etc inside my iPod touch?

For example, when I select Test1.xls in Drop box app, it should open in Documents free app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. You would need the Documents application to build in support for pulling down documents from your dropbox account. Applications on the phone aren't really allowed to share data because of sandboxing.

Comment: Well, because of this, I had to jailbreak and install cracked app. I really want to pay and use the app, as it is excellent but it seems that without credit card, I won't be able to purchase app from iTunes. Thanks for answering :-)

Comment: Can you purchase apps with iTunes gift cards? I would go and check first before buying any, but that might be one way to buy apps with cash. The other would be to buy American Express gift cards with cash, and then use those as a credit card for iTunes.

Comment: I live in India. I am not sure how to get an iTunes gift card. Actually I got one from Sun Microsystems (now Oracle) for $10, but I misplaced it and don't know where it is now.. Wish I had it now to buy this app :(